# CSS label:hover ~ .colaOutside .straw { transform: rotate(15deg); }　I hope when I hover over the straw can move deg. but it is not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, label, transform

```
[https://codepen.io/demi-chen/pen/jOrWwje][1]
```

label:hover ~ .colaOutside .straw {   transform: rotate(15deg); }

I hope when I hover over the straw can move 15deg. but it is not working. Anyone can help me? tks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI5Z3.png)do it like this, the problem will be solved
label {   width: 100%;   height: 100%;   display: block;   position: absolute;   top: 0;   z-index:999; }
label:hover ~ .colaOutside .straw {   transform: rotate(15deg); };

problem is line logic one under another

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you explain more about the line logic?